# Android Q not updating system images (unable to resolve dependency)

Tags: android, dependencies, android-10.0

In the SDK manager their showing update available for the Android Q but when i select any of the system images under the Android Q preview tab and click apply then error showing unable to resolve dependency.

see photo for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known and reported bug for Android Studio 3.3.2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129801155).

The only solution that I know of is to use one of the pre-release Android Studio versions. Or, live without the Q Beta 2 emulator images.

Comment: BTW, this is now finally working for Android Studio 3.4.